# Computer Modern Font Changes on Export from Texstudio in MacOS

Tags: fonts, pdf, mac, computer-modern

I'm using Texstudio to write in MacOS and, for now, I'm quite comfortable with using the Computer Modern font.
One of my documents looks like this when previewed in Texstudio:
[image: Document in Texstudio]

But when I open one of the automatically created pdfs (they just are made when I build and view the file) in the "preview" mac app the fonts all change like this:

[image: PDF in Preview App]

How do I make them look the same? I can't find the settings anywhere?

Comment: Welcome! As far as I can tell the font isn't changing; the applications just rasterize it differently. (Without and with anti-aliasing, probably.) If you zoom in sufficiently enough (or get a higher-resolution monitor, or print) they should look identical.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! 1) Presumably you're using a relatively modern version of TeX, so the document output you're making is always a pdf, that's what building the file means. 2) The fonts are embedded into the pdf, so no matter what device or viewer you use, per default it should use that embedded font. So like ShreevatsaR said, the viewers probably display the font differently, that will be the case with any font and document, not just Computer Modern and pdfs made from TeX.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Wow! That makes a lot of sense and I would like to note that the text actually looks a lot more different on the monitor to in the screenshot. It makes sense that it is just the way it is rasterised, thank you.